# How to best showcase selected state of visually important elements

Tags: gui-design, color, selection, hierarchy, states

I'm creating a feature to select profile badge – how might I best showcase the selected state?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Due to the diversity of colors and similar shapes, I would opt for a detail with contrasting shape and style (outlined):

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Dan for your suggestion. 

What about about the on-load state? Should the selected option be scrolled to the first? 

Comment: This is another question 

Comment: thanks Dan, i've asked another question & used the mock up you provided & credited you. appreciate it. 

https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/148780/selection-state-position-after-selecting-onload

Answer (score 0):

To enhance the visual impact, consider making the stroke a bit more prominent while keeping the overall simplicity intact. or ad a check mark inside the circle
[image]